# How do I convert a string input into ACSII values and then from ASCII into Binary in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm suppose to make a program that takes user input as a string like CAT and turn it into ACSII values but I'm not sure how I can do that. The only way I can think of is by writing out every variable like A = 65 but I'm sure there's more efficient ways of doing this. Also does the system automatically know 65 = A or do I have to put a code in front of the number so it knows I'm talking about ACSII and not just the number 65? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Heres my code!

```
public class SecretMessageDisplayer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is your secret message?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strMessage = scan.nextLine(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < strMessage.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print((int)strMessage.charAt(i) + " "); 
            System.out.print((int)strMessage.getBytes(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to get from ascii to binary.

Comment: Okay posted my code in my questions.

Comment: If you assume that String is an array of characters, and you want to convert each character to ASCII - how would you approach it? Hint see [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class documentation

Comment: @MaxZoom I would make the system print (char) of each individual letter in the string

Comment: I'm not sure how to target each individual character in the string though :/ Sorry im new to this.

Comment: Did you read **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)**  class documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate through your String like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("What is your secret message?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String strMessage = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < strMessage.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print((int) strMessage.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Java 8
    strMessage.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.print(c));
    System.out.println();

    // Binary output
    for (int i = 0; i < strMessage.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print("0"+Integer.toBinaryString((int)strMessage.charAt(i)));
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Java 8 Binary output
    strMessage.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.print("0"+Integer.toBinaryString(c)));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Results:

```
What is your secret message?
CAT
676584
676584
010000110100000101010100
010000110100000101010100
```

Comment: Ohhhh so thats how you iterate through the string okay thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyCaoWatsYourPowerLvl It was also shown in answer posted almost hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31462011/1393766 and mentioned in [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

Comment: Also from this how can I convert ASCII to binary code? ie A = 01000001

Comment: for binary output what is the point of putting the "0" at the start?

Comment: @JeffreyCaoWatsYourPowerLvl To make each character 8 bits in length (a byte).  Normally, the result would just be 7 bits.

Comment: Ohhhh I see is the only circumstance where it will print that 0 at the start for me when the number is greater or equal to 128? Also what is the difference between Integer.toBinaryString and .getByte?

Comment: @JeffreyCaoWatsYourPowerLvl Right, with ASCII characters you have to do this if you want 8 bits.  Extended ASCII characters you wouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a `char` to an `int` to get its ASCII value.

```
for(char c : someString.toCharArray()){
    System.out.println(c + " = " + (int)c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Java doesn't use ASCII but [Unicode Table](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

> does the system automatically know 65 = A

`char` is *numeric type* in Java which means you can write things like

- `'A'+1` to get value representing `B`,
- or `'H' - 'A'` to get value which can be used as position of `H` in alphabet.

It also means that system knows that `A = 65` but how it will *see* it depends on variable type you will use to store this value, if you use `char` it will be treated as `'A'`, if `int` it will be treated as `65`.

So if you need to *see* character as numeric value rather than symbol, simply

- place that character in `int` variable,
- or explicitly [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) it to `int`.

Example:

```
char ch = 'A';                // will represent 'A' symbol
int index = 'A';              // will represent index of A in Unicode Table, which is 65
System.out.println((int)'A'); // prints 65
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ASCII value by simply casting individual characters to `int` like so:

```
char character = 'a';    
int ascii = (int) character;
```

Simply loop through your string taking individual letters via `.charAt(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

this will do

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] carray = "CAT".toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {

        int iasci = (int) carray[i];
        System.out.println(iasci);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

```
String x="CAT";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)));
```